# drupal 7 Cannot open in ArchiverZip->__construct

Tags: drupal-7, zip

I'm using this code to extract zip file

```
$file = "/sites/default/files/xml_files/file.zip";
$obj = new ArchiverZip($file);
```

But this error is thrown:

```
Exception: Cannot open <em class="placeholder">/sites/default/files/xml_files/file.zip</em> in ArchiverZip->__construct()
```

I use this too:

```
$file = drupal_realpath(file_default_scheme() . '://')."/xml_files/file.zip";
$obj = new ArchiverZip($file);
```

But it thrown the same exception.

Any idea ? 
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following:

```
$archive_file = 'public://xml_files/file.zip'
$directory = 'temporary:///extracted_files'    
$archiver = archiver_get_archiver($archive_file);
$archiver->extract($directory);
```